Error creating RWA Metadata: unknown signer: 8YPeMc8CkWyW95SExgKz6o8pKuKfn1H3Bqvu6HWk81dX
#[program]
pub mod rwa_tokenization {
    use super::*;

    // Initialize RWA metadata and mint
    pub fn initialize_rwa(
        ctx: Context<InitializeRwa>, 
        uri: String, 
        name: String, 
        total_supply: u64, 
        price_per_fraction: u64
    ) -> Result<()> {
        // Validate the URI and name lengths
        require!(uri.len() <= 200, RwaError::UriTooLong);
        require!(name.len() <= 50, RwaError::NameTooLong);

        // Set up the RWA metadata
        let rwa_metadata = &mut ctx.accounts.rwa_metadata;
        rwa_metadata.uri = uri;
        rwa_metadata.name = name;
        rwa_metadata.creator = *ctx.accounts.creator.key;
        rwa_metadata.total_supply = total_supply;
        rwa_metadata.price_per_fraction = price_per_fraction;
        rwa_metadata.current_holders = 0;
        rwa_metadata.mint = ctx.accounts.mint.key();

        Ok(())
    }

   
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeRwa<'info> {
    #[account(
        init, 
        payer = creator, 
        space = 8 + // discriminator
                32 + // creator (Pubkey)
                32 + // mint (Pubkey)
                8 + // total_supply (u64)
                8 + // price_per_fraction (u64)
                8 + // current_holders (u64)
                4 + 200 + // uri (String max 200 chars)
                4 + 50 // name (String max 50 chars)
    )]
    pub rwa_metadata: Account<'info, RWAMetadata>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub creator: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = creator,
        mint::decimals = 2,
        mint::authority = creator,
    )]
    pub mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token2022>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}



#[account]
pub struct RWAMetadata {
    pub uri: String, // Max 200 characters
    pub name: String, // Max 50 characters
    pub creator: Pubkey,
    pub mint: Pubkey,
    pub total_supply: u64,
    pub price_per_fraction: u64,
    pub current_holders: u64,
}

#[error_code]
pub enum RwaError {
    #[msg("The amount exceeds the total supply")]
    ExceedsTotalSupply,
    #[msg("Calculation error")]
    CalculationError,
    #[msg("URI is too long (max 200 characters)")]
    UriTooLong,
    #[msg("Name is too long (max 50 characters)")]
    NameTooLong,
}


unknown signer error might occur when you try to send your transaction with a non-signer address.
In your test cases, is the creator address similar to that of your anchor workspace?
